# Want to use a SESSION variable in my PHP SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, session-cookies, html-entities

This has been driving me mad for weeks, I just want a $_SESSION variable included in a query.

It's worked on every other page but this one, this page and this specific one just WILL NOT WORK.

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM listings
    WHERE
    id = :id
    ";
    // Define our query parameter values
        $query_params = array(
            ':id' => htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
            );
```

Is what I have essentially wound up with, and as far as I know it should work like it has on every other page!

I've tried concatonating and echo of it, I've tried just session, I've tried POST, but it just won't seem to let it in.

Earlier in the page I have

```
<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>
```

As a test to make sure the value is there, and it works flawlessly.

I've also tried listing the "SELECTS" specifically and still nothing.

Here is the error PHP gives me: "Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound"

Comment: `$dbh->bindParam(':id', htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));` What happens if you try this?

Comment: @Daan * Put that in place of $Query_Params, no table appears and I receive no error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if it works,
assuming you have $db as your DB connection object

```
$query = "
SELECT
    *
FROM listings
WHERE
id = :id
";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have done the trick!

Bit much to ask I know, but could you possibly explain what it was I was doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$paramSession = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$query_params = array(YOUR_PARAMS)
print_r($query_params); //edit his post adding the output of this.
```

Comment: "Array ( [:id] => 4 ) Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound"

That 4 there is the id number of the user, that's the thing I want it to use...

Comment: If the value 4 being passed, your problem may lies in the implementation of the query.

Comment: try to set $query_params = array(':id' => 4) and execute.